# How to pass payload for elastic search aws post request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws4c

I am trying to fetch records for a particular index, I am able to get the default 10 records per call.

However, I would like to pass extra body paramters too so that I can do some filtering and limiting on records.

After following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Sigv4/Signer.html) link,
here is the code I am using,

```
    body = '{size:100}'
    payload_hash = OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256").hexdigest(body)

    url = "https://myhost/index_name/_search"
    signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
      service: 'es',
      region: 'us-west-1',
      access_key_id: 'access_key',
      secret_access_key: 'secret_key'
    )

    uri
     = URI(url)

    t = Time.now.utc
    amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')

    headers = {
      "host"=>'myhost',
      "x-amz-date" => amzdate,
      "x-amz-content-sha256" => body
    }

    signature = signer.sign_request(
      http_method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body
    )


    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'

    url = URI("https://myhost/index_name/_search")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url, 'size' => '100'})
    request["host"] = signature.headers['host']
    request["x-amz-content-sha256"] = signature.headers['x-amz-content-sha256']
    request["x-amz-date"] = signature.headers['x-amz-date']
    request["authorization"] = signature.headers["authorization"]
    response = http.request(request)
    result =  response.read_body
    result = JSON.parse(result)
    result["hits"]["hits"].count
```

I am always getting 10 records only.
I read a lot of documentation for net http too. Dont know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution, posting it below for future inquiries

I was adding body on request like `request['body']` which was setting it as a header. 
Correct way was to pass json body to signature hash and set body method of request object.

```
    body = {"size": 1000}
    payload_hash = OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256").hexdigest(body)

    url = "https://my-host/my-index/_search"
    signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
      service: 'es',
      region: 'us-west-1',
      access_key_id: 'accesss_key',
      secret_access_key: 'secret_key',
      apply_checksum_header: false
    )

    uri
     = URI(url)

    t = Time.now.utc
    amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')

    headers = {
      "host"=>'my-host',
      "x-amz-date" => amzdate
    }

    signature = signer.sign_request(
      http_method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body.to_json
    )


    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'

    url = URI("https://my-host/my-index/_search")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request["host"] = signature.headers['host']
    request["x-amz-date"] = signature.headers['x-amz-date']
    request["authorization"] = signature.headers["authorization"]
    request.body = body.to_json
    response = http.request(request)
    result =  response.read_body
    result = JSON.parse(result)
    result["hits"]["hits"].count
```